# ASP.NET Listview not saving edit

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use a listview to display and update marks. 
The data displays without any issues, however when I click edit, then insert data and try to save the changes, the listview fails to do so and loads in the same state is was prior to the update attempt. Any ideas what is going on?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="StudentResultsDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT Module_Info.ModuleTitle, Module_Info.UserID, Module_Info.ModuleCode, Modules.ModuleMarks, Modules.MarkID, Modules.ExamMark, Modules.AssignmentMark, Users.SNumber, Lecturer_Records.UserID AS Expr1  FROM Module_Info INNER JOIN Modules ON Module_Info.ModuleID = Modules.ModuleID  INNER JOIN Users ON Modules.UserID = Users.UserID INNER JOIN Lecturer_Records ON Users.UserID = Lecturer_Records.UserID WHERE (Lecturer_Records.UserID = @UserID)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Modules] SET [ModuleMarks]=@ModuleMarks WHERE [MarkID]=@MarkID" >  

<UpdateParameters>
<asp:FormParameter Name="ModuleMarks" Type="String" />
<asp:FormParameter Name="MarkID" Type="String" />
</UpdateParameters>
<SelectParameters>
<asp:SessionParameter Name="UserID" SessionField="grabUserID" />
</SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
        <!-- list view to display results-->
        <header class="jumbotron hero-spacer">
            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="listviewid" DataSourceID="StudentResultsDS"  DataKeyNames="ModuleMarks">
                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <span style="">ModuleTitle:
                    <asp:Label ID="ModuleTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ModuleTitle") %>' />
                    <br />
                    UserID:
                    <asp:Label ID="UserIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ModuleCode:
                    <asp:Label ID="ModuleCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ModuleCode") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ModuleMarks:
                    <asp:Label ID="ModuleMarksLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ModuleMarks") %>' />
                    <br />
                    MarkID:
                    <asp:Label ID="MarkIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MarkID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExamMark:
                    <asp:Label ID="ExamMarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ExamMark") %>' />
                    <br />
                    AssignmentMark:
                    <asp:Label ID="AssignmentMarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AssignmentMark") %>' />
                    <br />
                    SNumber:
                    <asp:Label ID="SNumberLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SNumber") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Expr1:
                    <asp:Label ID="Expr1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Expr1") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    </span>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <span style="">ModuleTitle:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ModuleTitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ModuleTitle") %>' />
                    <br />
                    UserID:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ModuleCode:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ModuleCodeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ModuleCode") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ModuleMarks:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ModuleMarksTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ModuleMarks") %>' />
                    <br />
                    MarkID:
                    <asp:Label ID="MarkIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MarkID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExamMark:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ExamMarkTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExamMark") %>' />
                    <br />
                    AssignmentMark:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="AssignmentMarkTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AssignmentMark") %>' />
                    <br />
                    SNumber:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="SNumberTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SNumber") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Expr1:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Expr1TextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Expr1") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    </span>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <span>No data was returned.</span>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <span style="">ModuleTitle:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ModuleTitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ModuleTitle") %>' />
                    <br />
                    UserID:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ModuleCode:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ModuleCodeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ModuleCode") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ModuleMarks:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ModuleMarksTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ModuleMarks") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExamMark:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ExamMarkTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExamMark") %>' />
                    <br />
                    AssignmentMark:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="AssignmentMarkTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AssignmentMark") %>' />
                    <br />
                    SNumber:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="SNumberTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SNumber") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Expr1:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Expr1TextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Expr1") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    </span>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <span style="">ModuleTitle:
                    <asp:Label ID="ModuleTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ModuleTitle") %>' />
                    <br />
                    UserID:
                    <asp:Label ID="UserIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ModuleCode:
                    <asp:Label ID="ModuleCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ModuleCode") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ModuleMarks:
                    <asp:Label ID="ModuleMarksLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ModuleMarks") %>' />
                    <br />
                    MarkID:
                    <asp:Label ID="MarkIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MarkID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExamMark:
                    <asp:Label ID="ExamMarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ExamMark") %>' />
                    <br />
                    AssignmentMark:
                    <asp:Label ID="AssignmentMarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AssignmentMark") %>' />
                    <br />
                    SNumber:
                    <asp:Label ID="SNumberLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SNumber") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Expr1:
                    <asp:Label ID="Expr1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Expr1") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    </span>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                        <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="">
                    </div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <span style="">ModuleTitle:
                    <asp:Label ID="ModuleTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ModuleTitle") %>' />
                    <br />
                    UserID:
                    <asp:Label ID="UserIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ModuleCode:
                    <asp:Label ID="ModuleCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ModuleCode") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ModuleMarks:
                    <asp:Label ID="ModuleMarksLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ModuleMarks") %>' />
                    <br />
                    MarkID:
                    <asp:Label ID="MarkIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MarkID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExamMark:
                    <asp:Label ID="ExamMarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ExamMark") %>' />
                    <br />
                    AssignmentMark:
                    <asp:Label ID="AssignmentMarkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AssignmentMark") %>' />
                    <br />
                    SNumber:
                    <asp:Label ID="SNumberLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SNumber") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Expr1:
                    <asp:Label ID="Expr1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Expr1") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    </span>
                </SelectedItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: ideas would be guesses with the information provided.  If you post your code, we could likely give you answers.

Comment: Thanks. I've copied my code now to the original post! :)

Comment: Try running a database profiler and examine whether the update is taking place, and whether the correct information is being passed in.

Comment: Doesn't look like the update is taking place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing it to a gridview which should allow the update to work. Try this code below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="searchStudentResults" cssClass="table table-hover" AllowSorting="True" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated1" >
             <Columns>

                 <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentNo" HeaderText="StudentNo" SortExpression="StudentNo" ReadOnly="true" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ExamMark" HeaderText="Exam %" SortExpression="ExamMark" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="AssignmentMark" HeaderText="Assignment %" SortExpression="AssignmentMark" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ModuleMarks" SortExpression="ModuleMarks" HeaderText="ModuleMarks" ReadOnly="true" DataFormatString="{0:0}"  />
                 <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" EditText="Add Marks"  ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary" ItemStyle-Width="100px" >
                <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-primary"></ControlStyle>

                <ItemStyle Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
                 </asp:CommandField>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="MarkID" ControlStyle-CssClass="hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden"  >  
                <ControlStyle CssClass="hidden"></ControlStyle>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="hidden"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="hidden"></ItemStyle>
                 </asp:BoundField>
             </Columns>
             <EmptyDataTemplate>
                 No marks to enter
             </EmptyDataTemplate>
         </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Will try this now Richard thanks for your help. You're a great guy